# Black screen on boot with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Kernel 3.15

Tags: 12.04, boot, 14.04, kernel, hp

I've installed Kernel 3.15.1-031501 and today 3.15.2-031502 because with 3.13 my HP 6730s has wrong fan control. But with both 3.15.1 and 3.15.2, after grub selection, something like 50% of boots fail! In these situations I can't access the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> so I have to reboot by long pressing power button. Someone can tell me what can I do? Thank you!

HW config:

- CPU Intel Core 2 Due T9400 (2.53 GHz, 6MB cache L2)
- RAM SoDimm DDR2 PC2-6400 800MHz 1x4GB Hynix + 1x2GB Micron
- Bridge Intel Mobile 4 Series
- HD Toshiba MK5055GS (500GB Sata)
- Ethernet Marvell 88E8042 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
- Wireless Broadcom BCM4312 (con driver b43 necessari per il kernel 3.15)
- Graphics Mobile Intel GM45 Express Chipset
- Audio Intel HD Audio Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not shure what was the issue, but now I'm running 3.15.3-031503-generic and all goes well. But I've purged old kernels with Ubuntu Tweak.